# Why is $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|X_n|^p] \leq B < \infty$ different from $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|X_n|^p] < \infty$ as a requirement?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, expected-value, martingales, supremum-and-infimum

This is part of a convergence theorem for $L_p$ martingales.

---

**Theorem**. We have $p > 1$ and $B>0$. Let further $(X_n)_n$ be a martingale with $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|X_n|^p] \leq B < \infty$. Then there exists a random variable $X_{\infty}$ such that $E[|X_{\infty}|^p] \leq B$ and s.t.

$X_n \longrightarrow X_{\infty}$ a.s. and in $L_p$ norm.

---

A powerful theorem but with a strong requirement condition. My question concerns this requirement. Why do we demand that

$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|X_n|^p] \leq B < \infty$ $(*)$

instead of just

$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[|X_n|^p] < \infty$ $(**)$

I know that, in general, these are different concepts. For example, only demanding that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$|X_n| < \infty$ does *not* imply that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |X_n| < \infty$

But in the case of $(*)$, we already have a supremum. And in my understanding, if $(**)$ holds, we must have some $B>0$ such that $(*)$ must also hold. Since if the supremum does not go to infinity, it must be smaller than some value.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The $B$ is there for the bound on $X_\infty$.  You could have do it without the $B$ but change that to $E\lvert X_\infty\rvert^p\leq\sup\dots$ and that's a lot of typing.

Comment: The point is that if you have the bound for all $X_n$, then you get the bound with the same constant $B$.

Comment: @user10354138 thanks I get it now. Although I would have preferred the longer version since the way the theorem is phrased above does not imply that the bound is tight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(*)$ and $(**)$ are both equivalent in that they tell you the sup is finite. $(*) $ gives a name to the sup ($B$), which can be used later.

So for a sequence $(a_n)$ both conditions: $\sup_n a_n<+\infty$ and $\sup_n a_n\le B<+\infty$ are equivalent. The latter obviously is equivalent to: $a_n\le B$ for all $n$, which is of course strictly stronger than: $a_n<+\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you, in your last sentence you probably meant $sup_n a_n < \infty$ since $a_n < \infty$ does not imply a finite supremum.

Comment: No, I cannot see an error there.